# JS - how can I dynamically add data and append it to DOM without a page refresh in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a todo list where I want to show all todos, todos flagged false (on click) and todos flagged true (on click). Each item has (for now here) only a title and a button, which (when clicked) flaggs the item (true).
I couldnt really find anything online that helped me. Any help much appreciated!
I have created a codepen so you can (hopefully) easier see the problem.

https://codepen.io/helloocoding/pen/XEXJJN?editors=1010

How can I do the following:

1: 
For all flagged items: When I click on the 'showFlagged' button I am being shown flagged items which is what I want. However, it should also show the newly added item too (without a page refresh). Here what I did was, calling the showNotFlagged function inside the function where I set flag to true. However, like this, when you click on the flag button (next to the added item), the whole list of showNotFlagged items is being shown.
How can I call the showFlagged function only if its already 'open', so add it to dom but not show it yet?

2: 
For not flagged items:
when I add new item, its flagged automatically false. How can I add the newly added item 'show Not Flagged list' without adding it to the dom yet? I cant call the function where I append all not flagged items because I just want to add new items, but not to the DOM yet.

HTML:

```
  <div>
    <input id="title" />
    <button type="submit" id="add">Add me</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="todoList"></ul>
  <button type="submit" id="showFlagged">Show Flagged</button>
  <button type="submit" id="showNotFlagged">Show not Flagged</button>

  <ul id="flaggedTodos"></ul>
```

JS:

```
function Todo(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.flag = false;
}

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  //showAll();
  var addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
  addButton.onclick = addItem;
  var flagedButton = document.querySelector("#showFlagged");
  flagedButton.onclick = showFlaggedTodos;
  var notFlagedButton = document.querySelector("#showNotFlagged");
  notFlagedButton.onclick = showNotFlaggedTodos;
}

function showAll() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  todos.map(function(item) {
    var li = create(item);
    listFragment.appendChild(li);
  })
  ul.appendChild(listFragment);
}

function addItem() {
  var title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  var todoItem = new Todo(title);
  var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var li = create(todoItem);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  saveItem(todoItem)
}

function create(todoItem) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  var titleElem = document.createElement("li");
  var title = document.createTextNode(todoItem.title);
  titleElem.appendChild(title);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  var buttonFlag = document.createTextNode("flag me");
  button.appendChild(buttonFlag);
  button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    isFlagged(todoItem, ev);
  })
  li.appendChild(titleElem);
  li.appendChild(button);
  return li;
}

function saveItem(todoItem) {
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  todos.push(todoItem);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function updateItem(todoItem) {
  console.log("3", todoItem)
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  var updatedItem = todoItem;
  todos.map(function(item, i) {
    if (todoItem.title == item.title) {
      todos.splice(i, 1);
      todos.push(updatedItem);
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function isFlagged(todoItem, ev) {
  todoItem.flag = !todoItem.flag;
  updateItem(todoItem);
  showFlaggedTodos();
}

function showFlaggedTodos() {
  console.log("called")
  var ul = document.getElementById("flaggedTodos");
  var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  todos.map(function(item) {
    if (todos.length > 0) {
      if (item.flag) {
        var li = create(item);
        listFragment.appendChild(li);
      } else {
        console.log("no flagged items")
      }
    } else {
      console.log("no items")
    }
  })
  ul.appendChild(listFragment);
  var flagedButton = document.querySelector("#showFlagged");
  flagedButton.onclick = "";
}

function showNotFlaggedTodos() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("flaggedTodos");
  var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  todos.map(function(item) {
    if (todos.length > 0) {
      if (!item.flag) {
        var li = create(item);
        listFragment.appendChild(li);
      } else {
        console.log("no not flagged items")
      }
    } else {
      console.log("no items")
    }
  })
  ul.appendChild(listFragment);
  var notFlagedButton = document.querySelector("#showNotFlagged");
  notFlagedButton.onclick = "";
}
```

Comment: You should use a library like Knockout.js

Comment: My question arised from the fact that I want to use vanilla javascript and no framework/library

Comment: That will be a lot of work and much riskier.  Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?